# techniques/methods/utilities/exercises to practise typography principles

Tags: website-design, cs6, design-principles, tools

I am a beginner interested in learning typography. What kind of tools are available that would help me layout/experiment easily with various design principles. For example, this [site](http://type.method.ac/) i found immensely useful to learn and practice kerning. Just wondering if there are any other such online/offline tools similar to above.

Comment: There are no specific 'tools'. It's just something you get better at the more you deal with typography and design.

Comment: @DA01, i edited the title to better reflect the intention of the question. I did find that website quite good to understand and compare my kerning skill to a pro's skill. Its immensely useful than reading books about kerning, at least at a beginner stage.

Comment: The thing about kerning is that it's as much subjective as objective. In the end, it's all about having an 'eye for details' and that mainly comes with experience.